# PrimeNG TurboTable sortable column sort indicator?

Tags: sorting, angular2-template, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I'm trying to transition an existing PrimeNG Datatable over to the newly-released TurboTable spec, and I've been able to get everything more or less working easily, but I lost the auto-generated sort direction indicators on column headers.

[image: Arrows on column headers]

Is there a built-in solution for displaying a sort indicator based on template binding provided by p-table, or do I have to attach to the p-table's `(sort)` event, figure out which column is sorted and what direction, and then update my template from a component method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a SortIcon component. Look at this example:

```
<th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
  {{col.header}}
  <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
</th>
```

Comment: Thanks, I legitimately didn't see this in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone had the same problem as me - had the `<p-sortIcon>` tag but the icons didn't show anyway - try installing the new PrimeIcons package (`npm install primeicons --save`) and including its .css file as a dependency (`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css" />`).